# Why doesn't Files.move recognize the CopyOption?

Tags: java, file

I am trying to move a File:

```
Files.move(path, path1, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

For some reason, it doesnt know neither REPLACE_EXISTING nor ATOMIC_MOVE.
CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING neither. Probably just got a mistake in the syntax, can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Can you link to the documentation of that field `CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`? I would like to know why you think it should exist if the compiler is telling you it doesn't.

Comment: Statically import `CopyOption` or reference it directly (`CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`)

Comment: @csmckelvey There´s none, just thought it would be a possible way, didn´t have my compiler at hand at the time.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the answer, unfortunaly it says REPLACE_EXISTING just doesnt exist for some reason....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`CopyOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/CopyOption.html):

> The StandardCopyOption enumeration type defines the standard options.

`CopyOption` is just an empty interface, `StandardCopyOption` is an enum which implements `CopyOption` and contains the standard options eg:

```
Files.move(path, path1, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Thanks. Just realized that I am stupid. Had that before. Said that it is no applicable for my arguments. Just realized that you have to insert paths and not strings. Thanks anyway!